# Isn't there anything/something you can do

Tags: difference, idiomatic-language, sentence-choice

Isn't there anything you can do to get her back?

Isn't there something you can do to get her back?

1. Are these equally natural and used interchangeably?
2. Which one sounds more frustrated on behalf of the person who the speaker is saying this to?

Answer (score 0):

Often, these two questions can be used interchangeably, but there is a nuance that some native speakers will be aware of: something can imply the expectation of a positive answer, and anything can expect a negative answer, so that "Isn't there anything you can do?" is more 'desperate' because it is already supposed by the questioner that the answer is 'no'.

[Something vs. anything](https://discover.hubpages.com/literature/Grammar_Mishaps__Something_vs_Anything)